# JavaScript: String extraction

Tags: javascript, string

If my String is like this:

```
var dollarValue = "$7.50;$15;50%";
```

What would be the best method of extracting each value? Each semicolon is used as a separator between the part of the string that matters. So like:

$7.50

$15

50%

I understand how to extract two values with only one semicolon, but I'm not sure how I would continue on down the string using each subsequent semicolon as the next starting point...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How 'bout [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)?

```
var arrayOfValues = dollarValue.split(";"); // ["$7.50", "$15", "50%"]
```

Comment: Does split just take the ";" and enter it into an array of it's own? I would then extract the information out of that newly created array, right?

Comment: @dcolumbus: `arrayOfValues[0]` will be `"$7.50"`, `arrayOfValues[1]` will be `"$15"`, etc. just like arrays work.

Comment: It will basically cut the string up on every semicolon, returning an array of the parts.

Comment: Perfect. It's these little things that I forget over time when I'm not constantly using it. Learning too many languages scrambles my brain.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `split` method:

```
var values = dollarValue.split(";");
```

This will return an array with the values between the semicolons.